# Check if value is there in static array

Tags: java, if-statement, compare

I have the following class:

```
public class ValueHolder {
    private String columnName;
    private int width;
    private String defaultColumnStyle;

    public String getDefaultColumnStyle() {
        return defaultColumnStyle;
    }

    public void setDefaultColumnStyle(String defaultColumnStyle) {
        this.defaultColumnStyle = defaultColumnStyle;
    }

    public String getColumnName() {
        return columnName;
    }

    public void setColumnName(String columnName) {
        this.columnName = columnName;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public ValueHolder(String columnName, int width, String cellStyle) {
        this.columnName = columnName;
        this.width = width;
    }

    public ValueHolder(String columnName, int width, String cellStyle, String defaultColumnStyle) {
        this(columnName, width, cellStyle, defaultColumnStyle, null);
    }

    public ValueHolder(String columnName, int width, String cellStyle, String defaultColumnStyle, String dataFormat) {
        this.columnName = columnName;
        this.width = width;
        this.defaultColumnStyle = defaultColumnStyle;
    }

}
```

and the following:

```
public class StaticArrayValues {

    public static ValueHolder[] TEST_VALUES = new ValueHolder[] {

            new ValueHolder("test Name", 4498, "testvalue"), new ValueHolder("Last Name", 4498, "testvalue"),
            new ValueHolder("test ID", 4498, "testvalue"), new ValueHolder("ID Value", 4498, "testvalue") };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String testValue= "First Name";
        
        // How do i check if testValue is there in  TEST_VALUES
        /*if(){
            
        }*/

    }

}
```

How do I check if "First Name" is there in TEST_VALUES=?

Comment: Your code suggests an underlying database... True? If so you should probably be querying at that level, not in the application logic... ?

Answer (score 2):

you have to iterate over the array

```
boolean isPresent = false;
for(ValueHolder valueHolder: TEST_VALUES){
  if(valueHolder.getColumnName().equals(testValue)){
     isPresent = true;
     break;
  }
}
```

Some additional thouhts,
If you are doing a lot of these (searching if a value exist in one particular field), then you can create a `HashMap` (HashMap<String, ValueHolder>) and put the `columnName` as key and ValueHolder objects as value, this will give you constant time complexity in lookups as opposed to the linear time complexity when iterating to through the entire list.

Answer (score 0):

Loop on the Array `TEST_VALUES` and check if `columnName` equals `testValue`

```
for(int i  = 0 ; i < TEST_VALUES.length ; i++){ 
    if(TEST_VALUES[i].getColumnName().equals(testValue)){
       //do whatever you want
       break; //if you to exit the loop and done comparing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recommend a 1) loop of some form 2) separating out the finding with the logic you wish to perform...

```
ValueHolder found = null;
for (ValueHolder each : TEST_VALUES) {
    if (each.getColumnName().equals(testValue)) {
       found = each;
       break;
    }
}
if (found != null) {
   // do stuff
}
```